# Configuring different parameters.yml paths on a per environment basis

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I need to place the `parameters.yml` in a different environment depending on the environment. In development it will be in `app/config` but in preproduction the path will change, same for the production environment and so on.

I know that the path of the `parameters.yml` is defined on the `composer.json`, inside the "incenteev-parameters" under "extra", but is there a way to configure it for different environments (like extra-dev or extra-whatever)?

The composer extra section looks like this:

```
{
 {
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

What I need is to make it different on every environment like:

```
{
 {
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
      "file": "/some/directory/config/parameters.yml"
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: The problem I'm having isn't in Symfony's configuration, I just have to  chage the resource value on the imports in the `config.yml`, `config_dev.yml`, etc to get it working.

The problem I'm trying to solve now is getting the `composer` `parameters.yml.dist` functionality working, because when I execute `composer install` it creates the parameters.yml file in the directory specified in the former `composer.json` snippet and not in the directory where the parameters.yml should be (the one that is dependent on the environment).

Comment: Move the resource: parameters.yml line from config.yml to the respective config_env.yml file and adjust the name accordingly.

Comment: @Cerad that's not the problem I updated the question explaining what the problem exactly is. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Personally I would just copy and edit.  I suppose you take a look at Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters and see if it supports passing the filename as an argument.